# Build Qt 5.0 with mingw

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, visual-c++-2012, mingw-w64

Ther's some way to build Qt 5.0 with mingw64 or Visual Studio 2012, or have I wait the next release?
I've tried the instruction to build qt 5.0 with mingw64 in the following link: http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit but seems I non way for me...
Does someone compiled Qt 5.0 with mingw64 (or Visual C++ 2012)?

Comment: What errors do you receive when you try to compile Qt?

Comment: I cannot build openssl it give me some assembly error... somthing releated with %ed

Answer (score 2):

check these prebuilt binaries for Qt for 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 32 and 64 bit, compiled with mingw-w64 (gcc 4.7.x I guess)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/external-binary-packages/Qt-Builds/